# Kickstart for BLE CC2541 programming

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to firmware programming and I need to program BLE CC2541. Where should I start as a beginner to understand the codes and alter it that I already have.

Answer (score 3):

While this question is likely to get closed as "Too Broad", I think I would make an attempt to get you started.

I hope you plan to go through documentation provided by TI guys. (CC2541 is Texas Instruments product)
While that document will explain how CC2541 works, you still need to know how BLE works and how it is implemented.
Its different than classic Bluetooth that BLE (generally) is preferred to communicate by means of service/s (with characterstic/s bundled up into them), be them Standard or Custom. Depending upon your area of application you can select one of the standard services implementation.
For more info on services, check [Bluetooth Developer Portal](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/BLE.aspx)

I guess, if you really want to have a good start at it, then understand these terms and their fundamentals:

1. Master device in BLE (Assuming that you know this already)
2. Slave device in BLE (Assuming that you know this already)
3. GATT Profile
4. GATT Database
5. GATT Client
6. GATT Server

---

Just to get you started:

### GATT Profile:

BLE allows you to send data over to the other device after establishing the BLE communication link, only via a defined way, called GATT Profile. Many a people refer the same as GATT Protocol. The data is transferred through characteristics which are bundled into services. There can be multiple services defined within the device and a service can be either the standard one or the custom service defined by a GATT developer.

### GATT Database

The structure of definitions of these services is known as the GATT Database. Where does this reside? Is the structure known to the Master as well as Slave?

### GATT Server

The BLE device which holds this GATT structure is a GATT Server, in your case the hardware having that CC2541 chip. The way GATT is to be developed and the chip is programmed with it, is entirely manufacturer dependent.

### GATT Client

Usually a BLE-enabled smartphone or Gateway device is the GATT client.
The GATT structure, more technically, the UUIDs of the services and the characteristics are shared between GATT Server and GATT Client. That is how BLE works, that is how a smartphone application reads a particular service from the BLE device.

Apart from this you need to know about GAP Service which handles the connection related things.

---

Welcome to StackOverflow! Coding is easy only if you know the concept well.

May be you would want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31042572/4228131): Getting no response whatsoever for similar reason.